# MouseUp в jQuery UI Droppable

Tags: jquery, css3, javascript, ui, html5

Здравствуйте, есть такая задача.

есть div

```
<div id="element1"></div>
```

и css

```
#element1 {
    widows:31px;
    height:31px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

этот див может перетаскиваться в другой див

```
<div id="contener">

    </div>
```

когда див `contener` принимает див `element1`, то диву `element1` надо дать вот эту картинку

```
<img src="images/1.png" width="250" height="31" />
```

дивов element1,2,3,4..... будет много и у каждого свая картинка, а принимающий див contener один
кто знает как это можно сделать?
я думаю надо в диве `contener` отследить событие отпускания мыши `mouseUp` дива `element1` и вставить ему картинку `images/1.png`. и так для каждого дива `element`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Вот так это делается.](http://jsfiddle.net/892eV/4/)